# How do I load multiple files in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, load

I have the following code to load a single matrix file in matlab

```
filename='1';
filetype='.txt';
filepath='D:\20170913\';
fidi = fopen(strcat(filepath,filename,filetype));
Datac = textscan(fidi, repmat('%f', 1, 640), 'HeaderLines',1, 
'CollectOutput',1);
f1 = Datac{1};
sum(sum(f1))
```

how can I load many files, say 1-100.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding a for-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include everything in a for loop that loops from 1 up to N_files, which is the number of files that you have. I used the function num2str() to convert the index i to a string. I also included the matrix sum in an array file_sums and a loaded_matrices cell array that stores all the loaded matrices. If all the loaded matrices have a known and same dimensions, you could use a 2D array (ex. loaded_matrices = zeros(N_rows, N_columns, N_files); and then load the data as loaded_matrices(:,:,i) = Datac{1};).

```
% N_files - the number of files that you have
N_files = 100;
file_sums = zeros(1,N_files);
loaded_matrices = cell(1,N_files);
for i=1:1:N_files
    filename=num2str(i);
    filetype='.txt';
    filepath='';
    fidi = fopen(strcat(filepath,filename,filetype));
    Datac = textscan(fidi, repmat('%f', 1, 640), 'HeaderLines',1,...
        'CollectOutput',1);
    loaded_matrices{i} = Datac{1};
    file_sums(i) = sum(sum(loaded_matrices{i}));
end
```